# Update pandas dataframe based on matching columns of a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, data-science

I have two pandas dataframes (**df_1**, **df_2**) with the same columns, but in one dataframe (**df_1**) some values of one column are missing. So I want to fill in those missing values from **df_2**, but only when the the values of two columns match.

Here is a little example what my data looks like:

df_1: [image: df_1]

df_2: [image: df_2]

I tried to add the missing values with:

```
df_1.update(df_2, overwrite=False)
```

But the problem is, that it will fill in the values, even when just one column matches. I want to fill in the value when the columns "housenumber" AND "street" matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `Multiindex` in both `DataFrame`s and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1 = df_1.set_index(["housenumber", "street"])
df2 = df_2.set_index(["housenumber", "street"])

df = df1.combine_first(df2).reset_index()
```

---

```
df = df1.fillna(df2).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem, exactly what I needed