# Updating a column value in pandas based on value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `pandas` data frames. `df` has original transactions while `df2` has corrections for few records of `df`. Below is example:

```
df.head()

month        name        amount
sep17        jon doe     2000
sep17        alex nelson 5000
.             .           .
.             .           .
dec17        alex g      9855
```

Above dataframe is how the values were recorded at the time of transactions. There are thousands of entries. But now I have another dataframe that has corrections to be made in original transactions for `amount` column. Please note that it does not contain all records but only those which needs to be corrected. Following is the example of second dataframe.

```
df2.head()

month        name        amount
sep17        jon doe     2100
.             .           .
.             .           .
dec17        alex g      8855
```

Now I just want to update the `amount` column of `df` with `amount` values from `df2` for the record with month and name that matches with `df2`. What would be the elegant way to do it?

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47311266/2901002) ? It seems like dupe.

Comment: Set them to the same index `(["month", "name"])` and do `df["amount"] = df2["amount"].values`

Comment: Tested, need `df = df2.set_index(["month", "name"]).combine_first(df1.set_index(["month", "name"])).reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . That worked! Please comment as answer so that I can give an upvote.

Comment: @SalA. - Unfortunately it was answered before, so if you can upvote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311266/update-pandas-dataframe-based-on-matching-columns-of-a-second-dataframe) answer. Thanks.